# php+mysql Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched the internet for troubleshooting with this "Call to undefined function mysql_connect() " error but none of the suggested procedures works...

When I try to access mysql from php, I get this error. I have PHP Version 5.2.17 and MySQL 5.1.68 (mysql is running outside php, I tried creating tables and databases etc.).

I uncomment the extensions in php.ini:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

and specified the path to these extensions.

I also added both PHP and MySQL to my PATH variable.
I am using Apache 2.2. and I restarted the server after every change that I made.

This is my code in php for accessing the database (but I suppose that the problem is not in syntax):

```
<?php     
      $dbhost = 'localhost';
      $dbuser = 'root';
      $dbpass = 'pasw';
      $dbname = 'db';

      $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
      mysql_select_db($dbname);
?>
```

I am out of ideas how to fix this, can u suggest some other troubleshooting tips? I am quite new to his problematics... I would like to use MySQL, cause thats what I will use on the actual server when I´ll have my website up and running. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: this is from apache log:

```
[Mon Mar 25 13:50:42 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\\Web\\thenemis\\dbconnect.php on line 7, referer: http://localhost/thenemis/admin.php
[Mon Mar 25 13:50:42 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Web/favicon.ico
```

EDIT2: this is from php info (I think that the problem may be with some unspecified parametres in php.ini file). I havent read anywhere that I should specify some other features than extensions and path to them but maybe I was wrong... what do you suggest?

```
mysql

MySQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links 0
Active Links    0
Client API version  5.0.51a

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysql.allow_persistent  On  On
mysql.connect_timeout   60  60
mysql.default_host  no value    no value
mysql.default_password  no value    no value
mysql.default_port  no value    no value
mysql.default_socket    no value    no value
mysql.default_user  no value    no value
mysql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode    Off Off
```

Comment: use phpinfo() to make sure that you edit correct php.ini

Comment: Are you using an AMP stack (lamp/wamp/etc)?

Comment: I installed php, mysql and apache separately (I dont use WAMp or anything)

Comment: Once I have broken `.dll` file. If nothing help from other answers try to download that files and replace exiting.

Comment: also, check if you have `mysqli_connect` available, maybe you have a "special" php build and you should use that

Comment: I edited the correct php.ini - I looked into phpinfo() page!

Comment: How do I check if a function is avaliable?

Comment: the mysql_* functions have been deprecated for a long time now. They should still be in your version but any way, you're better off using PDO or mysqli.

Comment: How do I check? Call to undefined function mysql_connect() <- not available

Comment: if you have no legacy code to run but just about to start writing a brand new one, then you shouldn't use these functions anyway - they are about to be deprecated. Start from using PDO. though you will need to uncomment pdo and pdo_mysql as well

Comment: @Kris for a long time? as a mater of fact, they aren't even deprecated yet. and mysqli is unusable the way it should be - so, it shouldn't be recommended at all.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: they *are* deprecated. The actual formal deprecation is coming in PHP 5.5 (now in beta release so will be out soon), but the PHP devs gave it a "soft deprecation" since at least 5.3 to try to wean people off using it. It may not have thrown warnings at you, but it was still deprecated in the sense that it wasn't recommended to use them. You're right that mysqli has issues but for people with existing mysql code, it's a lot easier to convert to it en-mass than to PDO so I do recommend it for that. For people writing new code there's absolutely no reason not to use PDO.

Comment: @YourCommonSense deprecated means scheduled for removal, not already removed. see http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799 from Sun Jul 10 12:03:36 2011

Comment: @Spudley just direct conversion from mysql to mysqli makes absolutely no sense - it is easier to keep with mysql in this case. Making use of prepared statements is the ONLY reason to move. So, either keep with mysql or move to PDO.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - well, I agree it's not ideal, but a direct conversion is still better than sticking with mysql, and Prep statements are not the only reason to switch - aside from the deprecation, which is a reason in itself, the old mysql extension has some known security issues which can be resolved with a simple switch to mysqli. As I say, certainly not ideal, and PDO is always a better choice, but a valid solution if you've got a large creaky code-base and not enough time/resources to convert it properly to PDO. (It's scary how many systems that description applies to)

Comment: @Spudley `"old mysql extension has some known security issues"` - it has not. `"which can be resolved with a simple switch to mysqli"` - it cannot. Where did you get that? What are these issues?

Comment: @YourCommonSense - This isn't the time or place to get into a debate about it, but... 1) Unencrypted communication between PHP and the mysql server (okay, if your mysql is on localhost this isn't an issue but over the network you really want it encrypted). 2) Poor charset support that makes it possible to use multibyte characters to bypass normal escaping under some circumstances.

Comment: Ok - its nice to debate about Mysql x PDO, but I really need to get MYsql working cause thats what I will use since its supported by my hosting provider... and I am absolutely clueless how to fix this localhost problem...

Comment: @Spudley it is always time and place to disclose a mistake. Charset support in mysql is EQUAL to one in mysqli. They are the same. mysql is as secure with charsets, as mysqli.

Comment: @Smajl did you try to google the very error message you've got?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it was already said use phpinfo() for determining if mysql is running correctly.
In general you should not use mysql anymore more but rather the new improved version of mysql, called mysqli http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php

You can in addition programmatically check if a function exists with method_exists method

Comment: Strange thing just happened. I restarted my PC and I got it somehow working. I restarted apache after every change but it didnt help. This somehow did so I solved the problem... Thanks for the answer anyway - phpinfo() did actually help a lot...

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'pasw';
$dbname = 'db';

<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

MySQL support will be removed of PHP, so start to use MySQLi or PDO instead.

:)

Answer (score 2):

Verify that your installation of PHP has been compiled with mysql support. Create a test php file containing `<?php phpinfo(); exit(); ?>` and run it in your browser. Search the page for keyword 'MySQL'. If you don't see it, you need to recompile PHP with MySQL support, or reinstall a PHP package that has it built-in.

Open your terminal and run bellow command.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

If you are running PHP you will also need to install the php module for mysql

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

I set the path for PHP in the system variable of my computer, edited the path value to `C:/program files/php;`
 and enabled `extension=php_mysqli.dll` in `php.ini`.

Then I used this function

```
mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password)or die(mysql_error());
```

And after that a system restart. It worked for me; I hope it works for you.